# Why the missing values aren't filled?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While using the pandas filling method on a data frame I am using median values of that specific column to fill the values, instead of filling it is being doubled.
Here's the missing values before :

```
id                                     0
perc_premium_paid_by_cash_credit       0
age_in_days                            0
Income                                 0
Count_3-6_months_late                  0
Count_6-12_months_late                 0
Count_more_than_12_months_late         0
application_underwriting_score      2974
no_of_premiums_paid                    0
sourcing_channel                       0
residence_area_type                    0
target                                 0
dtype: int64
```

Hence I used the following to fill the Na values:

```
train['application_underwriting_score'] = train['application_underwriting_score'].fillna(train['application_underwriting_score'].median(),inplace=True)
```

But instead of getting filled I am getting more Na values:

```
id                                      0
perc_premium_paid_by_cash_credit        0
age_in_days                             0
Income                                  0
Count_3-6_months_late                   0
Count_6-12_months_late                  0
Count_more_than_12_months_late          0
application_underwriting_score      79853
no_of_premiums_paid                     0
sourcing_channel                        0
residence_area_type                     0
target                                  0
dtype: int64
```

I already checked the median, which is coming out to be 92.1. What could be the possible fault in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need remove `inplace=True`:

```
train['application_underwriting_score'] = train['application_underwriting_score'].fillna(train['application_underwriting_score'].median())
```

Or:

```
train['application_underwriting_score'].fillna(train['application_underwriting_score'].median(), inplace=True)
```

Comment: Well it didn't solve the problem, but the following did:values = train['application_underwriting_score'].fillna(train['application_underwriting_score'].median())
train['application_underwriting_score'] = values                                                                                  Why using another variable to store the return value helped ?

Comment: @KUSHAGRAVIJAYKINJAWADEKAR - I think you need remove `inplace=True` if want assign back or remove assign back, edited answer.